# How do i apply style from one class to another, to all items inbetween

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, css-selectors

I want to add specific style property on all child elements between "day-start" and "day-end"

[image]

I've tried using code like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.day').forEach(
el => el.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(
el => el.style.color = 'red'
)
);
```

But not sure on how to add it between these two classes

Using jQuery solution of:

```
 $(".day-start").nextUntil(".day-end").addClass("foo");
```

adds class to the correct element but breaks on the table row tag + it does not include the .day-start + .day-end class

Would it be possible to add the class to all the content that has the background color added ? as a alternative solution?

Comment: You could maybe just use `<div>`'s instead of tables, and `display: grid;` then you can use the jQuery function. 

Comment: @BjørnNyborg valid point but I can't change the HTML structure unfortunately:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a selector for all the days, loop them, and then start adding the class when you get to the `.day-start` and stop adding when you get to the `.day-end`.

Something like:

```
var active = false;

document.querySelectorAll('.day').forEach((day) => {
    if(day.classList.contains("day-start")) {
        active = true;
    }
    if(active) {
        day.classList.add("foo");
    }
    if(day.classList.contains("day-end")) {
        active = false;
    }
});
```

I have created an example for you here: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/OJRJwEN

Comment: very good solution, mind me; what solution would you recommend if i only wanted to add the class to the day which contains the background-color styling inline, no matter what color the style is?

Comment: You could check if an element has a background color by using: `element.style.backgroundColor !== ''` for example. 

Answer (score 0):

You would need to track elements in between. Something like that:

```js
let section = 0; // our flag: 0 - before, 1 - in-between, 2 - after

document.querySelectorAll('.day').forEach(
    el => {
        if (section === 0 && el.classList.contains('day-start')) {
            section = 1;
        } else if (section === 1 && el.classList.contains('day-end')) {
            section = 2;
            // now, if this was a loop, we could simply `break;` it 
            // but `forEach` doesn't offer that
        }

        if (section === 1) { // we apply this logic only for divs in section 1
            el.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(
                div => div.style.color = 'red'
            )
        }
     }
);
```

With a loop, it would be a bit simpler:

```js
let isBefore = true;

for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('.day')) {
    if (isBefore && el.classList.contains('day-start')) {
        isBefore = false;
    } else if (el.classList.contains('day-end')) {
        break; // we're ending all iteration here
    }

    if (isBefore) continue; // we finish the current round here, and go to another `el`

    el.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(
        div => div.style.color = 'red'
    );
 }
```